# What is the meaning of "&^" operator?

Tags: go

I am a newbie of golang, and confused with the "&^" operator.

From the [spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec), the explanation of "&^" is: bit clear (AND NOT). Per my understanding, it means: x &^ y == x & (^y).

Is my understanding right? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your'understanding is right.
You can make it as a "bit operator"
And the rules:

```
1 &^ 1 = 0
1 &^ 0 = 1
0 &^ 0 = 0
0 &^ 1 = 0
```

Just like `x & y`, `x ^ y`, `x | y`.